# Sqlite Database Application

Tags: ios4, sqlite

I want to use same database object at Delegate file & Controller File of Custom Created databse header file which Contains object of type Sqlite3 & thee  methods
like OpenDB & CreateTable & InserData.

i m right now just beginner in iphone programming so, pls Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app delegate file is like a global file , you just import the your **Custom created database header file** in app delegate , and create the object of **Custom created database header file** , assuming the file name is **dbOperations.h**

in app delegate

import it and create its object, then , do property , synthesize and that's all.

in any view controller you just need to import your "appDelegate.h" file and make its object in view did load like

objAppdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

and you may access your all methods and members of **dbOperations.h** file by

**objAppdelegate.objdbOperations** .

whatever you put in appdelegate will remain shared and common to entire app , all viewControllers and all classes.

your createDatabase method should be like this, and call this method when your application did finished loading method of appDelegate file.

```
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase
{   
    appDelegate = (SexarobicsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir =[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
    //NSLog(@"%@", databasePath);

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath])
    {
        NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    }

    //Open DB Connection
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) 
        sqlite3_close(database);
    return; 
}
```

and firing sql query like this fashion, in above code @"database.sqlite" is your db file name.

```
-(void)getData
{
    selectStmt = nil;

     // fire query and perform those related operations

    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(selectStmt);
    selectStmt = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thnak you @Hadley for your support.
but my project build & run but i m getting three warnings & 
even connection to database could not opend.

Comment: Mr.@Hadley
what i m actually doing in above project see my next question.

Comment: probably you have not written the open database statement in your create database method. You need to open database before performing any of the DB operations (not sure about the case of select query but will be better if you open db in select operation too ).

Comment: i have written open database stmt in Implementation header.
which is **database.m**

Comment: Can you come online ,for chat ? , I'm sure we can heal the problem just within 2 mins.

Comment: Still if you want another easier way , you may go to this link and implement that tutorial   http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/  , i saw your profile , I'm from Morbi. :)

Comment: ya. i m able to chat with you.
just give me your gmail id.
i have added the code of Database header file in my second question 
pls just see it.

Comment: ya, as you like.....!!!
i m new to this site i dont know how this can happen?
only i can see that CHAT icon on toolbar above.
just tell me how can we chat.?
if you prefer may id is available to my profile.